Intermittent Docker network problem is happening
Device:Raspberry Pi 5 8GB
The only installed package is Docker for Raspberry Pi, and all of the application programs below are running after dockerizing.

Nginx Proxy Manager, Jenkins, some services I am working on

Network composition is provisioning several services at the same time, so I am trying to use only docker-network for security.
The network that NPM is attached is named 'main-net', and data obtained through inspect command of this network is as below.
$ docker network inspect main-net
[
    {
        "Name": "main-net",
        "Id": "488966e42093e1abe082c19e83443955855952df79207c331c0a4f08e12b2bb7",
        "Created": "2024-01-24T12:13:31.125832336+09:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2cc86409aed17c249b1d7724e2eca5a5010cf7f97e2cfb15d23ca2677114b085": {
                "Name": "my-service-container-name",
                "EndpointID": "8d781f8a59bdb5abd52a74712143c4bb7c9bf77392a59ea8ab40e5eb3b9cde54",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a74e49c05c1482a42141d34d194a5e2879d207dff1ec631acd7a0570643bc4f3": {
                "Name": "nginx-proxy-manager",
                "EndpointID":       "30b9b6b80dfa890dcbae4415a655918015ad198e42169ef4a835adad782de732",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ce25283e3f332aa925eb9ca35f1d4a7a5322b803a741334e045d4b35b4ea1a49": {
                "Name": "jenkins",
                "EndpointID": "df1da37a87db198f1e0fceeaac3488466118f4b68f6a8e9911d412532c5ac863",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
            ... More
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "main-net",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "host",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.24.1"
        }
    }
]

As it is shown through the lines above, NPM container and problematic service are on the same network. Reverse proxy was working fine when I finished composing them.
However, this problematic service throw 502 error when "my-service-container-name" container is updated and deployed with Jenkins.
In this case, ping test to "my-service-container-name" ip 172.20.0.4 shows below.
[root@docker-a74e49c05c14:/app]# ping 172.20.0.4
PING 172.20.0.4 (172.20.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.20.0.5 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.20.0.5 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.20.0.5 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable

Traffic is not delivered properly.
While testing Jenkins ip of another service shows proper traffic delivering between containers.
PING 172.20.0.7 (172.20.0.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.20.0.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.171 ms
64 bytes from 172.20.0.7: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from 172.20.0.7: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms

"my-service-container-name" container is running propely. docker ps command shows container has no problem.
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
2cc86409aed1   my-service-container-name          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:3500->4173/tcp, :::3500->4173/tcp                                              my-service-container-name

If host name is mapping as Local Ip address of "192.168.0.254:3500", but not as container name of "my-service-container-name:4173", page is working fine.
What could be the reason? Is it because of Docker for Raspberry Pi or did I set something wrong?

Attach: Part of my-service-container-name image composition file (composed with Vite + React) and Docker / docker-compose files

---- vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), svgrPlugin(), tsconfigPaths()],
    server: {
        port: 3000,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
    },
    preview: {
        port: 4173,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
    },

---- docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'
services:
  front:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '3500:4173'
    networks:
      - main-net
networks:
  main-net:
    external: true

---- Dockerfile
FROM node:20-alpine
RUN apk add yarn
WORKDIR /hcc
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 4173
CMD ["yarn", "preview"]

Currently I have no idea how to solve this problem. I would appreciate for any help.

It is a bit hard to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. But I noticed that you don't specify any ports in your ping commands.

@Tschösi ping(1) is a low-level network-debugging tool that uses an alternate protocol, ICMP, that doesn't have ports.  It's not necessarily that useful for debugging application-connectivity problems.

What is trying to call what?  The question talks about Nginx and Jenkins, but they're not described in the question at all; where are those running, what is trying to make a network call, with what host name or URL, and what error do you get?
